# Sitecore Certification question, Content Author cannot add components to a page

Tags: training-certification

I am preparing for the Sitecore Solution Developer Certification 9 Exam and I am not sure about the answer for the below question. Please help me to know the answer.
If someone can share a brief explanation of the answer then it would be great.

A Content Author cannot add components to a page location you've identified as the main placeholder. What is the possible solution for this issue?

```
1) You enable placeholders in sitecore.config.
2) You create a Placeholder Settings item.
3) You dynamically bind the Placeholder to the Layout.
4) You add a placeholder to Allowed Placeholders folder.
```

Comment: Answer is 2. You create a placeholder settings item and add the components allowed on that placeholder

Answer (score 0):

I find out some of the questions on the exam to be 'tricky' in some way. However, I would mark answer 2.
2) You create a Placeholder Settings item. - In order to add rendering to page there have to be placeholder available and placeholder item needs to have rendering in 'allowed controls' (edit: otherwise all renderings are allowed).

See some explanations about placeholders in here too: [https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8034/why-placeholder-settings-when-you-can-bypass-them#:~:text=Placeholder%20Settings%20are%20used%20if,with%20placeholder%20name%20Page%20Content](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8034/why-placeholder-settings-when-you-can-bypass-them#:%7E:text=Placeholder%20Settings%20are%20used%20if,with%20placeholder%20name%20Page%20Content)

Answer (score 0):

Above question was from the study guide provided by sitecore learning, so I put a support ticket. After that sitecore revised the options for the question. Now they have the **fourth** option as
"**You add the component to the allowed controls list of the placeholder settings**", which is the correct answer for the question.

Comment: Right, this has been taken far enough. This is not an exam solver site. You've already been given explanations and a direction in which to look and study further.